# Made Machine learning models with scikit-learn and Pandas but I think something's wrong with its accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was working with classification models with pandas and scikit-learning. I found that the accuracy of models were too high and all the same and I don't know why

```
decision_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("Test set accuracy = ", model.score(X_test, y_test))

Test set accuracy =  0.9615384615384616

logistic_regression = LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("Test set accuracy = ", model.score(X_test, y_test))

Test set accuracy =  0.9615384615384616

support_vector = SVC()
support_vector.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("Test set accuracy = ", model.score(X_test, y_test))

Test set accuracy =  0.9615384615384616
```

I expect the accuracy of classification models would be different with each other but its not, and I think its accuracy is too high. But I don't know what's wrong :( Would very thankful if you help..

Comment: what is model? you have a different name each time...but you always use the same thing: model

Comment: I have a table data which contains 0 and 1 binary data, and those are classification models applied to that table data..maybe
+)OH..!
++)So should I change that 'model' into other words?

Comment: model is undefined per se. You are not renaming the  `model` object. You are not computing the test accuracy for each model but for only one. you have not shared all the code or have been making a small mistake. Replace `model` by the model you trained ( such as `desicion_tree`)

Answer (score 1):

from the comments, you need to run this code:

```
decision_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("Test set accuracy = ", decision_tree.score(X_test, y_test))


logistic_regression = LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("Test set accuracy = ", logistic_regression.score(X_test, y_test))



support_vector = SVC()
support_vector.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("Test set accuracy = ", support_vector.score(X_test, y_test))
```

in your original code you always run `model`which is not definied in your code, this is why you received the same score

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately it is still the same score even after replacing my code.. but thank you for your help really

Comment: @Xappysmile, you need to retry this solution in a fresh new file or something because it fixes the one obvious problem with the code you shared.

Comment: if you use jupyter then do: restart kernel, is it a binary classification problem (two classes)